# How to handle Unicode issue with out ignore in python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-requests

How to handle Unicode issue in python 2.7 ?

I tried encode u'\xe3\x81\x93\xe3\x82\x93\xe3\x81\xab\xe3\x81\xa1\xe3\x81\xaf' in "utf-8" and output is coming :**ããã«ã¡ã¯** which is not supported.Is it possible at least some equivalent convertible characters.Please help me on this.

Value =u'Evaluation Period: Not In Use\nEvaluation Period Remaining: 89 days 23 hours 58 minutes\nRegistration Status: Registered ( 31 Oct 2019 06:37 ) Registration Expires on:  ( 30 Oct 2020 06:32 )\nSmart Account: InternalTestDemoAccount\n Account: \xe3\x81\x93\xe3\x82\x93\xe3\x81\xab\xe3\x81\xa1\xe3\x81\xaf\nLast Registration Renewal Attempt Status: SUCCEEDED on 31 Oct 2019 06:37\nLicense Authorization Status: Registered ( 31 Dec 1969 18:00 ) Authorization Expires on:  ( 31 Dec 1969 18:00 )\nLast Authorization Renewal Attempt Status:SUCCEEDED on 04 Nov 2019 03:48\nProduct Instance Name: myProduct\nTransport Setting'.encode('UTF-8')

Output:

Evaluation Period: Not In Use
Evaluation Period Remaining: 89 days 23 hours 58 minutes
Registration Status: Registered ( 31 Oct 2019 06:37 ) Registration Expires on:  ( 30 Oct 2020 06:32 )
Smart Account: InternalTestDemoAccount
 Account: **ããã«ã¡ã¯**
Last Registration Renewal Attempt Status: SUCCEEDED on 31 Oct 2019 06:37
License Authorization Status: Registered ( 31 Dec 1969 18:00 ) Authorization Expires on:  ( 31 Dec 1969 18:00 )
Last Authorization Renewal Attempt Status:SUCCEEDED on 04 Nov 2019 03:48
Product Instance Name: myProduct
Transport Setting

Comment: Where does `\xe3\x81\x93\xe3\x82\x93\xe3...` come from and what is it *supposed* to be…?

Comment: Can u please tell me how to convert unicode to string??.Input :u'\xe3\x81\x93\xe3\x82\x93\xe3\x81\xab\xe3\x81\xa1\xe3\x81\xaf' and output:'\xe3\x81\x93\xe3\x82\x93\xe3\x81\xab\xe3\x81\xa1\xe3\x81\xaf'

Answer (score 0):

When I convert from hexadecimal to utf-8 I get Japanese characters

```
code = '\xe3\x81\x93\xe3\x82\x93\xe3\x81\xab\xe3\x81\xa1\xe3\x81\xaf'
print code.decode("utf-8")
こんにちは
```

I don't understand how you've been doing the conversion. But it's possible that this is the problem.

I hope this helps you.

Comment: Please try below code:
code = u'\xe3\x81\x93\xe3\x82\x93\xe3\x81\xab\xe3\x81\xa1\xe3\x81\xaf'
print code.decode("utf-8")

UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-14: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: If we convert  unicode( u'\xe3\x81\x93\xe3\x82\x93\xe3\x81\xab\xe3\x81\xa1\xe3\x81\xaf) to string value('\xe3\x81\x93\xe3\x82\x93\xe3\x81\xab\xe3\x81\xa1\xe3\x81\xaf') that time it will work.But when I try to convert unicode to string that time it is throwing error

Comment: the problem is that by declaring it unicode.
The format is modified to 
u'u\'\\xe3\\x81\\x93\\xe3\\x82\\x93\\xe3\\x81\\xab\\xe3\\x81\\xa1\\xe3\\x81\\xaf\''
I don't know why this is happening.